# ImageMapster highlight all areas on .ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having difficult time solving one simple problem.

I need to highlight all areas on image when the page gets to `.onready()`.

This is the code I'm using... but it doesnt work.

```
   $(document).ready(function(e){
                    for(var area in areas) {
                            $(this).mapster('highlight', areas[area].key);
                                    }
                        });
```

And I am using [this ImageMapster plugin](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using each loop :

```
jQuery.each(areas, function(key, value) {
     $(this).mapster('highlight', key);
});
```

I dont know what data we get from areas, you can try to add console in each loop to see what we get in key and its value.

Comment: `data-mapkey="area-XXXX"` is the key value...and this wont work either...